# If I change all the data type of the struct to char , I get size of 6 even thought there are offsett for object layout

Tags: c, memory-alignment

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75842989/reducing-the-size-of-struct-by-changing-struct-member-declaration-order)
I have changed the ParticleTwo to

```
typedef struct ParticleTwo {                                                                 
    char type;                                                                               
    char m;                                                                              
    char x,y;                                                                              
    char vx, vy;                                                                           
} ParticleTwo;
```

I get the below

m 1

x 2

y 3

vx 4

vy 5

struct size --> 6

the above offset but there is the size of char for each which is 1 byte so what happened to get the whole struct size as 6 ?

[Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

[Data Alignment](https://hpc.rz.rptu.de/Tutorials/AVX/alignment.shtml)

Comment: Your structure has six `char` in it. What are you expecting?

Comment: The compiler is always right, the size of the struct is 6.

Answer (score 0):

1 byte data type or char data type can be place at any location on the memory address without any alignment or byte offset. The struct which contains all char data type are place after each other
type,m,x,y,vx,vy ( no offset between any)

type 0
m 1

x 2

y 3

vx 4

vy 5